# Software KM switch - not video

Tags: windows, networking, kvm-switch

Slightly odd request but somebody may have done it.
I have a bunch of windows PCs and not enough deskspace - so I would like a software KVM to simply switch key/mouse input between different networked machines.

BUT they are all running graphics intensive tasks (openGL and CUDA) so I don't want a remote desktop/VNC type solution - I need the video to be unaffected going to it's original monitor.

Comment: Are all monitors connected and running on each computer? You said not video, so I take away from that and picture a desk with say 3 or 4 monitors on it, all connected to different computers each with its own KB and Mouse under it. Is that the setup we are trying to rectify?

Comment: Well the picture is more like; piles of servers covering the floor with monitors and the occasional keyb/mouse balanced on top of them with a mess of cables covering everything - but yes!

Comment: Ah, but the monitors arent like, neatly next to eachother where something like Synergy would work nicely then?

Comment: @Paperlantern - synergy is exactly what I was looking for. I even remember using this on Linux but I thought it was part of X, I never knew it was an app. ps if you wan't to put this as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Done and done! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synergy would likely do exactly what you are trying to do. It ties separate machine's monitors together as if they were part of a single computer and desktop experience, even though they are entirely separate machines.

I used this when I had a three monitor setup with a dual windows machine and a single Linux Mint box to the right of that. One single keyboard and mouse. Very elegant. It sometimes isn't PERFECT, but it is a solid solution.